# Status of Ethereum Sync using Geth for Beginners

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

I am new to ethereum and right now getting the ethereum blockchain using geth with `syncmode=fast` and `cache=5120`

It's been quite some time the sync being running (about 24 hours) and still the process has not completed.

I was wondering what the current status is looking at the log, but I am not able to understand much.

Can anyone tell me what the below details signifies? What does each parameter states? Till which block has this synced and other relevant details?

```
INFO [10-25|16:25:13] Imported new state entries               count=1059 elapsed=7.024ms   processed=7515488 pending=7432  retry=43  duplicate=1175 unexpected=5305
INFO [10-25|16:25:24] Imported new block receipts              count=119  elapsed=230.181ms bytes=9326402   number=4220975 hash=6d6c23…ad8eb6 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:25:34] Imported new block headers               count=2048 elapsed=384.273ms number=4258047 hash=b0d55a…ad5e1c ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:25:38] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [10-25|16:25:40] Imported new block receipts              count=54   elapsed=121.085ms bytes=5344988   number=4221029 hash=0d3b58…6cd098 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:26:00] Imported new block receipts              count=85   elapsed=195.139ms bytes=7045657   number=4221114 hash=c92b6d…269d41 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:26:03] Imported new state entries               count=1011 elapsed=3.001ms   processed=7516499 pending=6882  retry=43  duplicate=1175 unexpected=5305
INFO [10-25|16:26:38] Imported new block receipts              count=213  elapsed=732.521ms bytes=14212804  number=4221327 hash=209065…a894a6 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:26:49] Imported new block receipts              count=87   elapsed=176.143ms bytes=5063052   number=4221414 hash=0381c0…bcab0b ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:26:52] Imported new state entries               count=840  elapsed=11.984ms  processed=7517339 pending=7749  retry=0   duplicate=1175 unexpected=5305
INFO [10-25|16:27:12] Imported new block receipts              count=230  elapsed=463.327ms bytes=13492139  number=4221644 hash=70ac9d…f71a29 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:27:21] Imported new block receipts              count=134  elapsed=336.239ms bytes=8628742   number=4221778 hash=606884…900f6b ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:27:22] Imported new block receipts              count=39   elapsed=83.059ms  bytes=2820211   number=4221817 hash=79185a…fb8d95 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:27:37] Imported new state entries               count=1101 elapsed=7.005ms   processed=7518440 pending=7128  retry=49  duplicate=1175 unexpected=5305
INFO [10-25|16:27:38] Imported new block receipts              count=141  elapsed=282.218ms bytes=10903446  number=4221958 hash=9c1fa2…fabd0a ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:28:03] Imported new block receipts              count=77   elapsed=158.113ms bytes=5838556   number=4222035 hash=b63474…f9303e ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:28:06] Imported new block receipts              count=97   elapsed=281.199ms bytes=10552582  number=4222132 hash=6ec7e1…f5f666 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:28:15] Imported new block receipts              count=8    elapsed=29.038ms  bytes=980919    number=4222140 hash=1e83fc…468077 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:28:21] Imported new block receipts              count=65   elapsed=172.126ms bytes=6943000   number=4222205 hash=1c02c9…ba76c2 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:28:23] Imported new state entries               count=1031 elapsed=6.003ms   processed=7519471 pending=6949  retry=0   duplicate=1175 unexpected=5305
INFO [10-25|16:28:34] Imported new block receipts              count=70   elapsed=203.144ms bytes=5500316   number=4222275 hash=af82fe…f5f069 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:28:34] Imported new block receipts              count=57   elapsed=185.133ms bytes=5040925   number=4222332 hash=97dedd…ddc765 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:28:52] Imported new block receipts              count=87   elapsed=183.129ms bytes=5341922   number=4222419 hash=a5021f…c35d4e ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:29:04] Imported new state entries               count=943  elapsed=7.004ms   processed=7520414 pending=7228  retry=0   duplicate=1175 unexpected=5305
INFO [10-25|16:29:17] Imported new block receipts              count=260  elapsed=606.449ms bytes=18195894  number=4222679 hash=b90f33…279604 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:29:30] Imported new block receipts              count=189  elapsed=346.227ms bytes=12584817  number=4222868 hash=56cc71…793e76 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:29:45] Imported new block receipts              count=97   elapsed=166.117ms bytes=5747857   number=4222965 hash=0faed2…93a29d ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:29:50] Imported new state entries               count=973  elapsed=9.978ms   processed=7521387 pending=6585  retry=0   duplicate=1175 unexpected=5305
INFO [10-25|16:29:57] Imported new block headers               count=2048 elapsed=367.242ms number=4260095 hash=835ba4…200585 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:30:06] Imported new block receipts              count=130  elapsed=234.183ms bytes=9658294   number=4223095 hash=505edb…482542 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:30:20] Imported new block receipts              count=219  elapsed=409.314ms bytes=15701288  number=4223314 hash=2e1e7f…f9dcf9 ignored=0
INFO [10-25|16:30:28] Imported new state entries               count=925  elapsed=10.006ms  processed=7522312 pending=7099  retry=63  duplicate=1175 unexpected=5305
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

As long as you see in the logs `INFO [xx-xx|xx:xx:xx] Imported new state entries ....` the network is syncing.

You can check progress with command `eth.syncing`(from the `geth console`), if syncing is on going you must see:

```
{                         
  "currentBlock": xxxxxxx,  
  "highestBlock": xxxxxxx,  
  "knownStates": xxxxxxx,   
  "pulledStates": xxxxxxx,  
  "startingBlock": xxxxxxx  
}
```

When process is complete you'll see `INFO [xx-xx|xx:xx:xx] Imported new chain segment ...` entries in the log.

Comment: I am, getting : Imported new state entries               count=1574 elapsed=19.493ms  processed=9560141 pending=18060  retry=117 duplicate=882 unexpected=3966.      Question: why does it say duplicate 882?

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have sync problems slow syncing etc, the easiest way to recover from this slowdown is to remove your blockchain data and restart Ethereum Wallet. Ethereum Wallet will then perform a fast sync which skips over these attack blocks.

**WARNING: Make sure you back up your keystore directory so you don't accidentally delete your account information.**

Shut down Ethereum Wallet.

Depending on your operating system, you will find the chaindata subdirectory in:

```
Linux - $HOME/.ethereum/geth
OS/X - $HOME/Library/Ethereum or $HOME/Library/Ethereum/geth
Windows - %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

Remove the chaindata directory.

Alternatively, you can run geth removedb to remove the blockchain data.

Start Ethereum Wallet. It should now start fast syncing the blockchain data. Alternatively, run

```
geth --syncmode "fast" --cache 1024 console
```

and then start Ethereum Wallet.

This works for me.

More [here](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Ethereum_Wallet_Syncing_Problems).